# Revert Local Copy of Project

Tags: svn

What's the best way to revert a local project, using subversion, to an older version? Bearing in mind I don't want to change the server version, obviously. I'm merely trying to compare the old to the new.

Would an `svn revert -r45678` do it? Or would that change stuff on the server?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to [svn update -r](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html)  your working copy to the required revision.

> svn update brings changes from the repository into your working copy. If no revision is given, it brings your working copy up to date with the HEAD revision. Otherwise, it synchronizes the working copy to the revision given by the --revision option.